# How to push array to object that doesn't exist in object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm very new to JavaScript. I was trying pushing new values to an object. But when I tried to push an array that doesn't exist in myObj, I got `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` error.
My code is below:

```js
var myObj = {
    first: "first value",
    second: "second value",
}

myObj.third.push(123)

console.log(myObj)
```

But when I check if it doesn't exist and create an empty array, then push it, it works. =>

```js
var myObj = {
    first: "first value",
    second: "second value",
}

myObj['third'] = myObj.third || []

myObj.third.push(123)

console.log(myObj)
```

I wonder if bottom code is best practice and if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Looks like you solved your own problem, you can't call push on a array until you initialize it.

Comment: You can also initialize the property with the initial value that you want to push, like so: `myObj.third = [123]`, from there, you can use `.push()` to add values

Comment: `push` is a method on `Array`. To create a property on an object you simply assign something to it.

Comment: I was expecting it to do in single comment ( creating a property that doesn't exist and pushing the value ). But it's seems my bottom code is way to go. @WilliamLohan

Comment: @Teyyihan Aksu ooooh you want `myObj.third = [123];`

Comment: No, actually 123 is dummy value. `myObj.third = [123]` is going to override the 'third' property's value isn't it? I want to insert new one to 'third' .

Comment: So you want a single line that conditionally initializes the array and pushes to to without being destructive if its run multiple times?

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON. JSON is a text format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `push` method is part of the `Array` prototype in your particular case you are trying to access a not defined property which in JavaScript is consider `undefined` so you are trying to do transalates into something like:

```
myObj.third.push => myObj.undefined.push
```

Because `myObj` does not have a `third` key you can try this in the console doing `console.log(myObje.third );`

So the engine returns an error saying that `undefined` does not have a property `push` that is only available in `Array`.

In this case you need to set assign a value to `myObj.third` before using it as an array, for that there are multiple ways to set the value as an array your answer above is one of those ways:

```
myObj['third'] = myObj.third || []
```

That line works however if for example `myObj.third` has a value will use that as a value as you are assigning the result of the operation `myObj.third || []` which in this scenario anything that evaluates as [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) will be returned if for instance you have:

```
myObj.third = true;
```

And then you do:

```
myObj.third.push(123);
```

An error will be displayed `Uncaught TypeError: myObj.third.push is not a function` as currently `myObj.third` is not an array.

So you need to make sure you are operating over an `Array` when using push, or at least when you initialize the value of your property is set as an `Array`, you can find more [details on `Array` construction on this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array).

Alternatives you can do to check before pushing are:

```
if ( ! Array.isArray(myObj.third) ) {
   myObj.third = [];
}

myObj.third.push(123)
```

Comment: Yes i tested the **true** error. But we will overcome this issue with a `if(myObj.third === Array)` condition. Then we will be sure it's an array

Answer (score 1):

Updated 2nd:

You could do a ternary operator

```js
let myObj = {
  first: 'first value',
  second: 'second value'
};

myObj.third = myObj.third ? [...myObj.third, 123] : [123];

console.log(myObj);
```

Comment: Yes i can. But when i would fetch data from API, i won't be able to tell if property is there or not until if condition. I was expecting it to do in single line of code.

Comment: Updated answer above